# Styling selected text .CodeMirror-selected

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Why overlap happens when I selected text ?
How fix this? In style.scss

```
.CodeMirror-selected {
  background: rgba($color-text,.3);
}
.CodeMirror-focused .CodeMirror-selected {
  background: rgba($color-text,.3);
}

.CodeMirror-line::selection,
.CodeMirror-line > span::selection,
.CodeMirror-line > span > span::selection {
  background: transparent;
  color: $color-text;
}
```

When I set background: $color-text; overlays are not visible, but I need transparency.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simple use color #373330, and resolved my problem.